# How to write log from gemfire function

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have a gemfire function which is ment to be deployed in a gemfire cluster. What is the way to write log from function, so that it goes to server log file.

My gemfire version is 8.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. From Gemfire 8.1.0 the log library they use has changed and it now uses Apache Log4j2. Logs done through this logger goes to the server log file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either the `LogService.getLogger(String)` or `LogService.getLogger()` method to get a `Logger` instance. The latter is a convenience method and sets the name of the returned `Logger` to the name of the calling class. The `Logger` returned by these methods is a `log4j` `Logger`.

Comment: I tried this but I don't find any getLogger method there. I am using gemfire 8.2.0

Comment: Can I directly use log4j